# Illustrator changes stroke direction (bug?)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6

I'm making something in Adobe Illustrator CS6 that has a stroke with '*charcoal - feather*' as brush definition. This gives the shape a asymmetrical, sketchy/smudgy look. To improve the look of the shape, I made a copy of the original, pasted it next to the first, and altered the second one to see which result I like better.

Now an unexpected problem arises: though the two shapes are nearly the same, the same stroke effect is reflected in the second shape. See the image below:

[image]

The only difference is that the teeth on the second skull are a bit rounder. Otherwise they are exactly the same. But for some reason, Illustrator decided that it's better to give the second one a stroke with its effect in the opposite direction.

I can't figure out how to fix this. I'm not sure if it's a bug or whether there's something I have overlooked?
Anyway, except for the teeth, the shape is the same (drawn with the pen tool). They both have a 3-point stroke with the same brush definition.
[image]

Things I have tried to fix this are:

1. going to the stroke options and ticking '*flip along*' and '*flip across*', but neither reflect the stroke vertically.
2. going to the brush options of the applied brush definition, and changing the direction of the brush stroke. If I do this and click OK, Illustrator gives me two options, *Apply to stroke* and *Leave strokes*. The first choice changes the direction of **all** shapes that use the same brush definition, the second doesn't do anything.
3. In the 'graphic styles' tab, I created a new style while having the original skull shape selected. Applying it then to the second gives me the exact same result.
4. on two web sites I found a workaround (see third post [here](http://68.adobe-illustrator-windows.overzone.net/reverse-stroke-t5378.html)) as a solution that involves clicking anchor points with the pen tool. Like with my first fix attempt though, I can only get it to reflect the stroke horizontally by doing this.

So am I missing an important option? What am I to do with this?

Comment: The stroke may reverse if you use the pen tool on a point it also may change the starting point of the curve. This is more of a feature than a bug tough.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to reverse the order of anchors in a path?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/53198/is-there-a-way-to-reverse-the-order-of-anchors-in-a-path)

Comment: @GeorgeC This question is 5 years old.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not actually reversing the stroke, it's just starting from a different point.

If you select the point (using the direct selection tool [image]) at the top of the second skull and click this button [image] it will split the here and force Ai to start the stroke there.

Comment: Nice, that brings me closer to the solution. However, the result isn't completely satisfying. It looks a bit more like the first one, but still different and now both at the top and at the bottom there is a 'fade' in the stroke. Any idea on how to get past this?

Comment: It seems like the path breaks somewhere down on the bottom right-hand side of the graphic, You'll need to figure out where it is breaking and join the two points.

Comment: After a few tries (perhaps I cut at an anchor point next to the one I tried earlier) I got it to work. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely too late for you, but for everyone else...

You can change the direction of the stroke by going into your Brushes panel.
Follow path: **Window > Brushes > Options of selected object > Flip along**

This will 'reverse' the brush stroke :)

Comment: Thanks, but as stated in the question I did try that already.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a script to [reverse the direction of the path](http://illustrator.hilfdirselbst.ch/dokuwiki/en/skripte/javascript/wr-reversepathdirection)

Comment: Cool, I never knew you could use javascript in Illustrator! How do I implement this though?

Comment: Here's a quick tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=072tQefb0_4