# Is there a way to reverse the order of anchors in a path?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg, path, brush, anchor-point

Is there any way to reverse the order of anchors in a path? I don't want to redraw the path again. I want to change the starting anchor point from the starting point of any path to its end.
reversing the order of the anchors I already drew has some benefits to me, like:

1. Applying an art brush without flipping the direction of the brush in the stroke options dialogue.
2. If I want my SVG to appear in any webpage in the order that I want, like a drawing stroke animation effect.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes there is.

If your path is **open**:

1. Select the pen tool (P)
2. Click the last anchor of the path. The order will be reversed

If your path is **closed**:

1. If the path is a compound path, skip to step 4
2. Select the path with the Selection Tool (black arrow, V)
3. Click on `menu->object->compound path->make`. The path will be turned into a "compound path"
4. Open the Attributes window (`menu->window->attributes`)
5. Use the "Reverse path direction" buttons (they are only available for compound paths).

[image]

Note: If you cannot see these buttons it is because the Attributes window is "minimized", so it is not showing all the attributes. Click on the top right corner and select "Show all".

Answer (score 3):

Another way is through a script: [reverse path direction script](http://kelsocartography.com/scripts/#wolfgang)

Answer (score 1):

In the version of Illustrator I'm using (CC 2015) this is really simple:

1) Open the Stroke palette (Window>Stroke), and go to the bottom right corner and there is a little button to the right of the line profile (see screen shot below). Click that button to reverse point direction.

[image: Screen shot of Stroke Palette, Reverse Direction button]