# How do I change the starting point of a closed path

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, anchor-point

I made some shapes that I later made into just paths. I want to change the type of stroke it has by applying a brush to it but the path is starting off at an undesired anchor point. How can I change where the path starts instead of just flipping it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to reverse the order of anchors in a path?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/53198/is-there-a-way-to-reverse-the-order-of-anchors-in-a-path)

Comment: The edit was necessary and the scars provided helped me out. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Split the path and rejoin it. An example:

[image]

1. A new closed path
2. Arrow brush is applied, it shows the start (=the same as the end)
3. Scissors are applied in the middle of the red circle, it's now an open path.

Selecting the path and pressing Ctrl+J joins the ends. The new starting point remains

4. The result is tested by moving the new start&endpoint with the direct selection tool

Comment: Oh of course! That would've been so simple! Thank you

Comment: @RexUmbra consider also to accept this answer and add something to the question.

Answer (score 1):

An easier option is to use the [WR-reversePathDirection](http://illustrator.hilfdirselbst.ch/dokuwiki/en/skripte/javascript/wr-reversepathdirection) script, which does exactly what you need in one step.